# PhoneGap - cannot locate javac.exe

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm new to PhoneGap and I tried to install and work as the starting guide shows but
its so complicated...

so here is my problem:

1. I have downloaded phonegap to c:\boaz\mobile\ directory.
2. To the same place I've downloaded the Java SDK.
3. I have set the PATH environment with the platform-tools and tools as the guide in 
   phonegap shows.
4. I have created a JAVA_HOME variable assigning it the value of: c:\Program Files(x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\ and i checked to see if there is a javac.exe file...and its there...
5. Finally i set the PATH and assign it also c:\Program Files(x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\

BUT

when I try to create a project it says:

[image]
What shall i do?

Comment: Type echo %PATH% to verify that your enviroment is set correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create.bat file

change 
line 24

IF [%%~$PATH:X]==[] (

to

IF [%%~$PATH:%%X]==[] (

Comment: Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Why? Some explanation would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a space in after "Program Files" in the path. I.e.

instead of C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\

try C:\Program **Files (x86)**\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that you have set JAVA_HOME to point to the wrong directory.

> I have created a JAVA_HOME variable assigning it the value of: c:\Program Files(x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\ and i checked to see if there is a javac.exe file...and its there...

You should really have set it to point to `c:\Program Files(x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_21` ; i.e. the root directory of the JDK installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly set two environment variables, PATH, and JAVA_HOME.

JAVA_HOME should be set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51 
(or whatever the latest version of the JDK is)

PATH should contain "%JAVA_HOME%\bin"

to check correct installation, type javac -version from C:\

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue when i setup the phonegap what I done is I create user variable call PATH not the system variable, just new user variable

my User variable PATH is -

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Program Files\ANT\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools;
```

It will work fine..